# Setup to allow creating new tables in PostgreSQL replica

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-master-replication

My goal is to create a replica of an existing database that would allow me to create new tables and populate them. I don't care about writes to replicated tables - those can and probably should throw errors.

Ideally I would like to accomplish this with standard postgresql streaming replication, but since that's not possible (or is there a way to do it?) I can go with a battle-tested and maintained extension. The least desirable solution would be a custom ETL process.

The replicated database will be used for analytics not real-time operations so synchronization delay is acceptable.

This seems like a fairly obvious use-case but I've been having trouble with finding any solution to this problem.

Comment: Check [PostgreSQL documentation about replication solutions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/different-replication-solutions.html), [Slony](http://slony.info) and [Bucardo](https://bucardo.org/wiki/Bucardo) should be able to have your replicate the tables you want, and still create others.

Comment: https://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/

Comment: Or maybe just use a foreign data wrapper to access the tables remotely

Comment: Do you need the writes on the replicated database to reflect on the slave?

Comment: pglogical looks most promising to me at the moment since it does not require external processes and looks like an upgrade to trigger-based solutions. @a_horse_with_no_name wouldn't foreign data wrappers need to be defined in the master? And no, I don't need master-master if that's what you're asking.

Comment: No, the foreign data wrappers are defined on the server that wants to read data from the master. The master does not need to be changed for that.